# cs50 Credit issue with identifying card company

Tags: cs50

I'm completely new to programming and have been working through pset1 this week but credit is proving to be a bit tough. I've managed to get the checksum working but I'm having real trouble identifying which company the card belongs to, the last part of the code seems to introduce more errors every time I try to fix it. I would really appreciate it if anybody could point me in the right direction.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

  long long ccnumber;

  do
  {
    ccnumber = get_long_long("Credit card number: ");
  }
  while (ccnumber < 0);

  long long cc = ccnumber;
  int s1;
 
  while (cc > 0)
  {
     int l1 = cc % 10;
     s1 = s1 + l1;
     cc = cc / 100;
  }  
 
  cc = ccnumber / 10;
  int s2; 
   
  while (cc > 0)
  {   
    int l1 = cc % 10;
    l1 = l1 * 2;
    if (l1 > 9) l1 = l1 % 10 + l1 / 10;
    s2 = s2 + l1;
    cc = cc / 100;
  }

  int s3 = s1 + s2;
  if (s3 % 10 == 0)
  s3 = true;
   
  long long n = ccnumber;
  int count = 0;
  while (n != 0) 
  {
    n /= 10;    
    ++count;
  }

  int twonumbers = ccnumber;

  while(twonumbers >= 100)
  {
    twonumbers = twonumbers / 10;
  }

  int firstnumber = ccnumber;

  while(firstnumber >= 10)
  {
    firstnumber = firstnumber / 10;
  }

  if (twonumbers == 34 || 37 && (count == 15 ))
    printf("AMERICAN EXPRESS\n");
  else if (twonumbers == 51 || 52 || 53 || 54 | 55 && (count == 16 ))
    printf("MASTER CARD\n");
  else if (firstnumber == 4 && (count == 13 || 16 ))
    printf("VISA\n");
  else
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ending if statements are not correct:

```
if (twonumbers == 34 || 37 && (count == 15 ))
...
```

should be

```
if ((twonumbers == 34 || twonumbers == 37) && (count == 15 ))
```

And the same for each if statement - you have to repeat what is being compared for every or statement or the compiler will assume "true" as in this case, 37 is no equal to 0.

Not, you can also compare ranges as well:

```
else if (twonumbers >= 51 && twonumbers <= 55 && count == 16)
```

Note I also correct a binary or there on the last compare (you had only 1 | and not 2 ||)

The last is

```
else if (firstnumber == 4 && (count == 13 || count == 16 ))
```

I also question what:

```
int s3 = s1 + s2;
if (s3 % 10 == 0)
  s3 = true;
```

is doing as this will actually always be "true" in a C sense, but in reality, you don't actually use `s3` anywhere so I am confused.

Lastly, turn on all compiler warning.  It would have told you about a lot of the things I mention here.

Now, I am not saying that this is the only thing wrong here, but it was the most obvious.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense, thank you so much for your time!